# Yaml merge key with multiple levels, ruamel.yaml produce incorrect output or i misunderstand yaml?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

Recently during edit of a bit complex yaml config i need to do a bit tricky yaml merge key operation and i noticed that my favorite tool ruamel.yaml produce illogical results.
I know that merge keys is deprecated, but as soon as 1.3 specs are not released, i have to keep using it.
I filled [`ticket`](https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml-cmd/tickets/11/), but author set it as invalid and stated that i misunderstand yaml.

Here is example of yaml code to test merge:

```yaml
tag1: &tag1
  subtag1:
    subsubtag1:
    subsubtag2:
       ssstag31:
       - var1
       - var2
       ssstag32:
       - var1
       - var2

tag2: 
  <<: *tag1
  subtag1:
    subsubtag2:
       ssstag31:
       - var3
       - var4
```

I expect that first it will merge tag1 anchor to tag2, then replace subtag1 by new data.
So tag2 will look like this

```yaml
tag2:
  subtag1:
    subsubtag2:
      ssstag31:
      - var3
      - var4
```

ruamel.yaml unfortunately does merge, but doesn't replace data, so tag2 is identical to tag1.

It is easy to test it by trivial python program which produce results i expect.

```py
import yaml

class NoAliasDumper(yaml.SafeDumper):
    def ignore_aliases(self, data):
        return True

with open("example.yaml") as f:
    y = yaml.safe_load(f)
with open(r'merged.yaml', 'w') as file:
    yaml.dump(y, file, Dumper=NoAliasDumper)
```

Please advise where I went wrong if python does the right merge and the ruamel.yaml doesn't. What is correct results of merge? As it means bug is either in python yaml or in ruamel.yaml

P.S. By the way, it's funny to check this snippet in online utilities that deal with it with varying degrees of success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "ruamel.yaml unfortunately does merge tag1 anchor to tag2".

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from pathlib import Path


file_in = Path('expand.yaml')
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(file_in)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

this gives exactly the original input:

```
tag1: &tag1
  subtag1: 42
  subtag2: baz
tag2:
  <<: *tag1
  subtag1: 18
  subtag3: *tag1
```

So it preserves both the aliases and merge key. (**I am using a smaller example than yours, but more complete
in that not all the keys of the merge are "covered" by other keys and that the anchor is still referenced if the merge key is
removed**).

You can ignore aliases in ruamel.yaml, but the effect is not really useful.

```py
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.representer.ignore_aliases = lambda x: True
data = yaml.load(file_in)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
tag1:
  subtag1: 42
  subtag2: baz
tag2:
  <<:
    subtag1: 42
    subtag2: baz
  subtag1: 18
  subtag3:
    subtag1: 42
    subtag2: baz
```

IIRC the `merge-epxand` option of the `yaml` utility (as provided by the package `ruamel.yaml.cmd`) was made before the `ruamel.yaml` package
could preserve merges. That options relies on the mapping_flattener of the `SafeLoader` (the `RoundTripLoader`'s doesn't
flatten in order to not loose the merge key information). But either the improvements on the PyYAML original
(which handles duplicate keys incorrectly), or the interaction between the aliases and merge keys caused that to not function
properly.

Unfortunately you cannot use PyYAML's flatten_mapping, as it errors with the less than useful message:

> expected a mapping or list of mappings for merging, but found mapping

But you can do:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from pathlib import Path

def flatten_mapping(self, node):
    merge = []
    index = 0
    while index < len(node.value):
        key_node, value_node = node.value[index]
        if key_node.tag == 'tag:yaml.org,2002:merge':
            del node.value[index]
            if isinstance(value_node, ruamel.yaml.nodes.MappingNode):
                self.flatten_mapping(value_node)
                merge.extend(value_node.value)
            elif isinstance(value_node, ruamel.yaml.nodes.SequenceNode):
                submerge = []
                for subnode in value_node.value:
                    if not isinstance(subnode, ruamel.yaml.nodes.MappingNode):
                        raise ConstructorError(
                            'while constructing a mapping',
                            node.start_mark,
                            f'expected a mapping for merging, but found {subnode.id!s}',
                            subnode.start_mark,
                        )
                    self.flatten_mapping(subnode)
                    submerge.append(subnode.value)
                submerge.reverse()
                for value in submerge:
                    merge.extend(value)
            else:
                raise ConstructorError(
                    'while constructing a mapping',
                    node.start_mark,
                    'expected a mapping or list of mappings for merging, '
                    f'but found {value_node.id!s}',
                    value_node.start_mark,
                )
        elif key_node.tag == 'tag:yaml.org,2002:value':
            key_node.tag = 'tag:yaml.org,2002:str'
            index += 1
        else:
            index += 1
    if bool(merge):
        values = [k[0].value for k in node.value]
        for k in merge:
            if k[0].value in values:
                continue
            node.value.append(k)

file_in = Path('expand.yaml')
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# Using PyYAML's flattener doesn't work 
# import yaml as pyyaml
# yaml.Constructor.flatten_mapping = pyyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.flatten_mapping 
yaml.Constructor.flatten_mapping = flatten_mapping
# uncomment next line if you don't want aliases
# yaml.representer.ignore_aliases = lambda x: True
data = yaml.load(file_in)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which I think gives what you want:

```
tag1: &tag1
  subtag1: 42
  subtag2: baz
tag2:
  subtag1: 18
  subtag3: *tag1
  subtag2: baz
```

So your ticket was not invalid.